# Alamofire - pre-procces response before responseJSON

Tags: ios, alamofire

I use `sessionManager.request` with `.validate().responseJSON`

Is it possible to modify response, that I get from server, before it is passed to `responseJSON` ? I need to do some strings stuff before it gets parsed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the response as `Data` and convert it to `String`, process and then convert it to `JSON`, this is the way I know if someone have a better please post it

this is an example code, I think you can get the idea with this

```
    let request = Alamofire.request(CustomizationManager.sharedInstance.getRequestUrlWithParameters(startDate: tupleDate.0, endDate: tupleDate.1), method: .get/*, parameters: CustomizationManager.sharedInstance.getDefaultParameters(), encoding: URLEncoding.queryString*/, headers: CustomizationManager.sharedInstance.getHeadersDict()).responseData { (response) in

        if(response.result.isSuccess){
            if(response.data != nil)
            {
                let string = String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8)
                let JSONResponse = CustomizationManager.sharedInstance.cleanStringAndConvertToJSON(dirtyString: string!)

            }
        }else{

        }


    }

    debugPrint(request.description)
```

this is my `cleanStringAndConvertToJSON`

```
   func cleanStringAndConvertToJSON(dirtyString:String) ->SwiftyJSON.JSON
    {
        var cleanStr = dirtyString.replacingOccurrences(of: "callback=\(self.defaultParameters["callback"]!)(", with: "")
        cleanStr = cleanStr.replacingOccurrences(of: ");", with: "")
        return SwiftyJSON.JSON(data: cleanStr.data(using: .utf8)!)
    }
```

Hope this helps